# SATA hard drive not spinning up when connected to USB port

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, usb, sata

When I connect a SATA HDD out of a fat Playstation 3 to a USB port on a laptop using a sata to usb converter board and cable the HDD does not spin up, however I know the cable and board are not bad because other HDD's work fine and others do not spin up.

How can I fix this so that I can browse the drives contents. it worked fine when it was connected to another PC running the same OS but not this one.

Comment: Attach a proper power source to the USB adapter. The USB ports are probably no delivering enough power (assuming you used the same adapter on the other PC).

Comment: @Seth the power source is an AC-DC transformer that came with the converter board.

Comment: is it plugged in when you have performed the tests?

Comment: @Blaine yes, it is plugged in

Comment: do you have a way of verifying the power adapter works? or even better, another one you can test it with?

Comment: @Blaine the power adapter worked on the other computer.

Comment: hmm... well then, that is peculiar. Presumably you're sure the usb port on the new computer works. Try all the ports just to be safe (might be a difference between usb 2 and 3 also)

Comment: @blaine tried that, the drives work fine if I connect them to the sata ports on the main board of the laptop (i.e on the bottom of the laptop) too.

Comment: are there drivers for your "converter board"?

Comment: what's puzzling is at the end of the day it sounds like a not enough power issue

Comment: if you have a live cd of linux, you might try it on that

Comment: @blaine, sorry I dont have a linux disk, basically in the external configuration my 3.5 ' HDD powers up but the two 2.5 ' HDDs do not.

Comment: well then, I'm somewhat at a loss...

Comment: It's probably the board itself since it does not sound like a software problem now. I'll probably just buy a 4 slot HDD enclosure or something. saves having HDDs all over the desk.